# How should I store trivial data in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, web-applications, metadata

I have a web application which allows people to upload flipbook animations. There are always a lot of requests for new features such as:

Tagging users (Like tagging a person in a Facebook post)

Tagging their flipnotes (think: Tagging YouTube videos with categories, or tagging Stack Exchange questions: `database-design`)

Linking their flipnotes to multiple relevant channels for a better chance at finding viewers

For things like follows/subscriptions, I have a table called `follows`.

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| followID      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| followingUser | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| followedUser  | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm rather hesitant to start creating dozens of tables to deal with metadata, however. There's just too much of it. I'm also hesitant about using TEXT datatypes to store, say, arrays of tags. I've heard bad things about efficiency; and I'm dealing with hundreds of thousands of rows in one part of the site, and almost four million in a single table in another. Small inefficiencies don't always stay small when you consider scalability. Take `order by rand()` as an example.

So, what approaches might I consider for storing and organizing trivial information in my database? I could significantly improve the user experience if I were able to keep track of more information.

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but wouldn't it be better if you dropped the followID field in the example above and set (followingUser, followedUser) as the PK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and most efficient way to do tagging is to create a master list of tags and then use a many-to-many relationship to record which tags are applied to each of your `FLIPBOOKS`.  Consider this ERD:

[image: ERD]

The `FLIPNOTE_TAG` table is just a simple intersection that contains foreign keys to your `FLIPNOTE` table and your `TAG` master list.  How you get tags depends on your business rules.  In Stack Exchange, tags are a moderated list of items.  On YouTube, they are just dumb strings that can be added pretty much at will by users.

Either way, having a master list of tags makes searching for distinct tags to follow or view much easier.

Also, unlike doing a partial text match search on arrays of strings, which is painfully slow at any reasonable scale, searching the foreign key index of an intersection table for one or more tag keys is very fast and scalable.

Comment: Hm, this gives me a lot to think about. Well, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think the follows database is quite well structured to be honest, but you only need either followingUser or followedUser (I would go for the latter and called it userBeingFollowed for better clarity) as if Person A is following Person B then it's automatically true that Person B is being followed by Person A and so you don't need both. Also, you need a timestamp column to record the time that the following took place and you should stored it as a long (or BigInt(11)).

The SQL statement is a simple INSERT query which is very easy to understand.

Comment: Actually, that's my mistake. You do need both id's for each user.